# Dodge Neon SRT-4

Tags: dodge, performance, neon

My SRT-4 is putting out the proper boost and pulling vacuum, but it's not pulling the right amount. When I bought the car in 2008 it was pulling about 20hg, but it sat for three years and now it is only pulling 10hg. I have looked at every hose and line and didn't see anything wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you say all the hoses and clamps are in good order, then the only other things that come to mind are the wastegate and exhaust manifold. Either the wastegate is opening too soon, or the exhaust manifold is leaking from the gasket or a crack. This would mean that either you lose boost too early, or you never get enough boost in the first place.

Or, if you're lucky, it's simply a case of having a blocked intercooler (bits of debris, a colony of mice, SPIDERS!) or a dirty air filter.

If you're *really* unlucky, it could be that your turbo decided that it's the perfect time to retire.